# What are the default locations for mailbox storage for Apple Mail?

Tags: mail.app, email, gmail

I'm trying to sort out my `~/Library/Mail` folder.

I access some emails outside of the Mail client, so I need to know where emails wind up, and it seems to have changed a bit with gmail in particular.

First, does Mail now store all the actual gmail messages in `~/Library/Mail/V2/IMAP-me@gmail.com/[Gmail].mbox/All Mail.mbox`? I note that I have mailboxes corresponding to the gmail labels, and which act like mailboxes in Mail itself. IIRC Mail used to actually put gmails into those mailboxes, but not sure.

Second, is it a default for the Mac OS to keep old email accounts forever? Whenever I delete an account from Mail it leaves the entire IMAP-me@oldaccount.com email mailbox structure intact. I assume I can move these off my SSD. Does Spotlight still index them?

Finally, any way to associate attachments with their respective emails without somehow going through the Mail client?

Comment: Q1- yes, Q2 -yes, Q3 - ?

Comment: Thanks. Now I've got a different problem; I figured I'd solve Q3 by importing into mail and then exporting into a generic mbox, and hope that the attachments went with. But no matter what I do, I cannot export from Mail. Not even existing mailboxes; the "export..." stays grayed out no matter what I select. Aargh.

Comment: You can only export as PDF, or save as Text file, but not in email format.

Comment: Just a thought that might not be super-related, but Apple Mail seems to be a space hog in general. Perhaps another option like Airmail, Postbox, or something would do better?

Comment: Turns out a bundle I was using (one of Indev's) caused the problem. Remove that and I'm good.

Comment: BTW, exporting makes an mbox, not a PDF or text. So it provides another option.